# multiple joins laravel php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a blog app, it has three tables that I want to look into for any search query.

Three tables: `posts` ,`categories`,`tags`.

Models:

**Post:**

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

    public function tags(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag','post_tag','post_id','tag_id');
    }

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','author_id');
    }
}
```

**Tag:**

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    public function posts(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post','post_tag','tag_id','post_id');
    }
}
```

**Category:**

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table='categories';


    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
}
```

**Table Structure**

```
/*Table: posts*/
----------------

/*Column Information*/
----------------------

Field        Type              Collation        Null    Key     Default  Extra           Privileges                       Comment  
-----------  ----------------  ---------------  ------  ------  -------  --------------  -------------------------------  ---------
id           int(10) unsigned  (NULL)           NO      PRI     (NULL)   auto_increment  select,insert,update,references           
created_at   timestamp         (NULL)           YES             (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references           
updated_at   timestamp         (NULL)           YES             (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references           
title        varchar(255)      utf8_unicode_ci  NO              (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references           
body         text              utf8_unicode_ci  NO              (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references           
slug         varchar(255)      utf8_unicode_ci  NO      UNI     (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references           
category_id  int(10) unsigned  (NULL)           YES             (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references           
image_path   varchar(255)      utf8_unicode_ci  YES             (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references           
author_id    int(10) unsigned  (NULL)           NO      MUL     (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references 



/*Table: tags*/
---------------

/*Column Information*/
----------------------

Field       Type              Collation        Null    Key     Default  Extra           Privileges                       Comment  
----------  ----------------  ---------------  ------  ------  -------  --------------  -------------------------------  ---------
id          int(10) unsigned  (NULL)           NO      PRI     (NULL)   auto_increment  select,insert,update,references           
name        varchar(255)      utf8_unicode_ci  NO              (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references           
created_at  timestamp         (NULL)           YES             (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references           
updated_at  timestamp         (NULL)           YES             (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references   

/*Table: categories*/
---------------------

/*Column Information*/
----------------------

Field       Type              Collation        Null    Key     Default  Extra           Privileges                       Comment  
----------  ----------------  ---------------  ------  ------  -------  --------------  -------------------------------  ---------
id          int(10) unsigned  (NULL)           NO      PRI     (NULL)   auto_increment  select,insert,update,references           
name        varchar(255)      utf8_unicode_ci  NO              (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references           
created_at  timestamp         (NULL)           YES             (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references           
updated_at  timestamp         (NULL)           YES             (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references 

/*Table: post_tag*/
-------------------

/*Column Information*/
----------------------

Field    Type              Collation  Null    Key     Default  Extra           Privileges                       Comment  
-------  ----------------  ---------  ------  ------  -------  --------------  -------------------------------  ---------
id       int(10) unsigned  (NULL)     NO      PRI     (NULL)   auto_increment  select,insert,update,references           
post_id  int(10) unsigned  (NULL)     NO      MUL     (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references           
tag_id   int(10) unsigned  (NULL)     NO      MUL     (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references
```

What I was trying to look for is for any search query, suppose if he enters `doughnuts` it should be matched for the `post title` or `category name` or `tag name`, if any of the match occurs post related to it, should be shown in the search results.

**What I tried**

```
$post = DB::table('posts')
  ->join('categories', 'posts.category_id', 'categories.id')
  ->join('blog_users', 'blog_users.id', 'posts.author_id')
  ->join('post_tag', 'posts.id', 'post_tag.post_id')
  ->join('tags', 'tags.id', 'post_tag.tag_id')
  ->select(
     'posts.*', 'blog_users.name',
     'post_tag.tag_id', 'post_tag.post_id',
     'tags.name', 'categories.name')
  ->where(function($query) use ($search) {
    $query->where('posts.title', 'LIKE', $search)
          ->orWhere('categories.name', 'LIKE', $search)
          ->orWhere('tags.name', 'LIKE', $search);
  })
  ->paginate(5);
```

But this seems to give me duplicated results and did not work well.

I would like to know a better solution for this problem?

Comment: @Lionel Chan did you try to `groupBy('id')`

Comment: @Gayan I didn't ask this question :)

Comment: My bad! @Lionel Chan pardon me. @BOTJr. did you try to `groupBy('id')`. And take a look at my answer and see if it fits your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I find myself using multiple joins in a query (specially in `SELECT` queries) what I usually do is implement a database `view` to encapsulate the logic behind the query.

Create migration like this

```
DB::statement("DROP VIEW IF EXISTS view_post");
DB::statement(" 
CREATE VIEW view_post
AS
SELECT 
    'posts.*', 
    'blog_users.name AS blog_users_name',
    'post_tag.tag_id', 
    'post_tag.post_id',
    'tags.name AS tags_name', 
    'categories.name AS categories_name'
    FROM posts
        INNER JOIN categories
        ON (posts.category_id = categories.id)
        INNER JOIN blog_users
        ON (blog_users.id = posts.author_id)
        INNER JOIN post_tag
        ON (posts.id = post_tag.post_id)
        INNER JOIN tags
        ON (tags.id = post_tag.tag_id)
 ");
```

Then make a model like this

```
class PostView extends Post { // <- To inherit properties of POST to here
    protected $table = 'view_post';
}
```

Then you can simplify your query like

```
$post = PostView::where(function ($query) use ($search) {
            return $query->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', $search)
                ->orWhere('tags_name', 'LIKE', $search)
                ->orWhere('categories_name', 'LIKE', $search);
        })
            ->groupBy('id')
            ->paginate(5);
```

What is important to keep in mind is that it's all depend on the situation.
To me for my station this was a much cleaner approach rather than muddy up my query. I think you could adopt this approach too. Thanks.

Note: you may need to modify the `view` and the `query` further to represent what you are trying to achieve.